# flutter : Firebase token returning null getToken, error fetching instanceID:

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-notification

I'm trying to get the FCM token using the `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3` version.
Getting the error `getToken, error fetching instanceID:`
FCM token returns a null value.

```
  static final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging=FirebaseMessaging();
  static String token;


_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
      _firebaseMessaging.configure();

      token=await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      String token2 = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
        assert(token != null);
        print(token);
        return token;
      });
      print(token2);
```

Comment: you're using a "then" and an "away" for the same method... you should be doing one OR the other. Have you tried fetching the token from the current logged user?

Comment: I tried both ways one by one but they both returning null. Yes, I tried to fetch the token from the currently logged user.